# how to add and remove items from dropdown based on another dropdown items in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, html-select, dropdown

I've 4 dropdown elements in which there were 10 security questions. Security questions are coming from database and its just one call. I've taken an array of securityquestions where in each array element consists of 10 questions.

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm col-sm-6">
                        <div class="row col-sm-9">                            
                                <select class="form-control selectpicker selector" name="selectedQuestion1" [ngModel]="selectedQuestion1" (ngModelChange)="filterSecurityQuestions($event,0)">
                                    <option [value]="0"  disabled selected>Select Secuirty Question1</option>
                                    <option *ngFor="let securityQuestion of securityQuestions[0]"  [value]="securityQuestion.SecurityQuestionID" >
                                        {{securityQuestion.Question}}
                                    </option>
                                </select>  <br />                       
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="securityAnswer1" placeholder="Your first security answer">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-sm-6">
                        <div class="row col-sm-9">
                            <select class="form-control selectpicker"  name="selectedQuestion2" [ngModel]="selectedQuestion2" (ngModelChange)="filterSecurityQuestions($event,1)" >
                                <option [value]="0"  disabled selected>Select Secuirty Question2</option>
                                <option *ngFor="let securityQuestion of securityQuestions[1]" [value]="securityQuestion.SecurityQuestionID">
                                    {{securityQuestion.Question}}
                                </option>
                            </select>      <br/>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="securityAnswer2" placeholder="Your second security answer">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-sm-6">
                        <div class="row col-sm-9">
                            <select class="form-control selectpicker"  name="selectedQuestion3" [ngModel]="selectedQuestion3" (ngModelChange)="filterSecurityQuestions($event,2)" >
                                <option [value]="0"  disabled selected>Select Secuirty Question3</option>
                                <option *ngFor="let securityQuestion of securityQuestions[2]" [value]="securityQuestion.SecurityQuestionID">
                                    {{securityQuestion.Question}}
                                </option>
                            </select>      <br/>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Street" name="securityAnswer3" placeholder="Your third security answer">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-sm-6">
                        <div class="row col-sm-9">
                            <select class="form-control selectpickerc"  name="selectedQuestion4" [ngModel]="selectedQuestion4" (ngModelChange)="filterSecurityQuestions($event,3)" >
                                <option [value]="0"  disabled selected>Select Secuirty Question4</option>
                                <option *ngFor="let securityQuestion of securityQuestions[3]" [value]="securityQuestion.SecurityQuestionID">
                                    {{securityQuestion.Question}}
                                </option>
                            </select>      <br/>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="City" name="securityAnswer4" placeholder="Your fourth security answer">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

---

Below is the typescript code to add and remove items from dropdown. In the below code,questionNo is the item selected(say 1,2,....10) in the dropdown and securityQtnDropdownNo is the dropdown number (say 1,2,3,4).

```
 filterSecurityQuestions(questionNo: number, securityQtnDropdownNo: number) {
        var duplicateSecurityQuestions = [];
        var min: number = 0;
        var max: number = 3;

        duplicateSecurityQuestions = this.tempArray.map(x => Object.assign({}, x));

        while (securityQtnDropdownNo < max) {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.securityQuestions[max].length; ++i) {
                if (this.securityQuestions[max][i].SecurityQuestionID == questionNo) {
                    this.securityQuestions[max].splice(questionNo-1, 1);
                }
            }
            max--;
        }

        while (securityQtnDropdownNo > min) {
            for (let j = 0; j < this.securityQuestions[min].length; ++j) {
                if (this.securityQuestions[min][j].SecurityQuestionID == questionNo) {
                    this.securityQuestions[min].splice(questionNo-1, 1);
                }
            }
            min++;
        }
    }
```

Basically, If I select an element in 1st dropdown , the same element has to be removed in rest of the dropdowns. And, If I change an element in the same dropdown, It should add the previous Item(Item before changing in the dropdown) to the rest of the dropdowns and remove the latest selected item (that is selected in dropdown1) in rest of the dropdowns.

---

Note that API call actually get 10 objects which have securityID and securityQuestion. I can easily remove items from rest of the dropdown as I get selectedValue from dropdown $event. But, I don't know how to add items back as I don't have previous value(i.e value before change event happen in dropdown). Please kindly help me on this.

Comment: are the selects always chosen in order? Select 1 then 2 then 3. So 10 selections in the first one, 9 in the second, 8 in the third? Or are they able to answer in any order they want? 2nd dropdown, third, then first

Comment: also, are the security questions in securityQuestions[0] the same as securityQuestions[1]? Each element in the 10 arrays is equal to each other? In that case.. whats the point of letting them pick the order? Just trying to understand the requirements, then I can probably help build the logic

Comment: Firstthing, there is no order in selecting security questions. User may select any question from any dropdown. The thing is if the user selected Q1 in Dropdown1, then he shouldn't see the Q1 in any other dropdown.

Comment: Yes,security questions of  securityQuestions[0] are same as securityQuestions[1] . that is reason we are trying to remove an element from other dropdown which is being selected. Note that we have 2 dimentional array here . securityQuestions[i][j] . i represents dropdown where as j represents question.